# how to read a text file stored in mobile using j2me midp2.0?

Tags: java-me, mobile

HI ALL,

I am working in j2me midp2.0 environment.My application wants to read a text file which is stored in mobile device.How to read the text file programatically using j2me.Please give me idea to get this.What is the root folder in mobile to place the text file for accessible from j2me Application environment.

Saravanan.P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need javax.microedition.io.file.FileConnection

Get root folder:

```
  try {
        Enumeration roots = FileSystemRegistry.listRoots();
        while(roots.hasMoreElements()) {
            System.out.println("Root: file:///"+(String)roots.nextElement());
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
    }
```

write to file

```
        public void write(String root) {                
        FileConnection fc = null;
        String fName = "test.txt";
        try {
            fc = (FileConnection) Connector.open(root + fName, Connector.READ_WRITE);
            if(!fc.exists()) {
                fc.create();
            }

            DataOutputStream dos = fc.openDataOutputStream();
            dos.writeUTF("test-test");                

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                fc.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
}
```

read from file

```
public void read(String root) {
        FileConnection fc = null;
        try {
             fc= (FileConnection) Connector.open(root + "test.txt", Connector.READ);
             DataInputStream dis = fc.openDataInputStream();
             String data = dis.readUTF();
             System.out.println(data);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                fc.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Hi oxigen,Here, where i mention the text file name ? please guide me

Comment: i am running my application in netbeans. But it raising below Errors at runtime Root_dir is:file:///root1/
[ERRR] [fileconnection] Error: javacall_fileconnection_is_directory(), cannot get file attributes

[ERRR] [fileconnection] Error: javacall_fileconnection_dir_exists(), cannot access directory

java.io.IOException: Target file doesn't exist

Comment: sorry, it's my problem.. I solved its working  fine... thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Better u use FileConnection.

```
FileConnection fc=(FileConnection)Connector.ope(url);
```